# PowerShell Set-Variable not handling ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName

Tags: powershell

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Set-Variable) `Set-Variable`'s `-Name` and `-Value` both support ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName but the following code doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    name="Test"
    value="1234"
} | Set-Variable -Force

$Test
```

Which results in:

```
name value  
---- -----  
Test 1234
```

If I use a ForEach-Object instead I get what I expected:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    name="Test"
    value="1234"
} | ForEach-Object { 
    Set-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Force 
}

$Test
```

Which results in:

```
1234
```

I noticed that `-Value` also supports ValueFromPipeline not using the property name, maybe that is related to this behavior.

Am I missing something that is needed for `Set-Variable` to accept a values for the parameters `-Name` and `-Value` from the pipeline by property name?

Comment: Where are you setting the value "testing"? It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Sorry, I pasted output from an old run of my test, I have corrected it, hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: Why `| Set-Variable -Force` instead of just using an assignment?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The context around why is more in the larger code base that I am working with that has an object with properties Name and Value that I would like converted into a PowerShell variable but I have tried to distill the question into something concise. I would like to use `| Set-Variable` and it seems what I am trying to do is supported by the documentation but doesn't work.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I can confirm that this happens in PS v5.1.14393.953, so it shouldn't be an outdated version issue.

Comment: It is my opinion that you have found a bug with that cmdlet where the ValueFromPipeline is taking precedence over ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, effectively disabling the latter. I would suggest submitting a bug report on the [PowerShell UserVoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell) site. Which reminds me that I meant to submit pretty much the same bug for `Set-Content`. I should go do that now.

Comment: I have submitted a bug ([link](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/18940891-valuefrompipeline-taking-precedence-over-valuefrom)) which should cover this as well as my observations with `Set-Content`.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician voted!

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Voted, do you want to post an answer that I can accept that says this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [this bug](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/18940891-valuefrompipeline-taking-precedence-over-valuefrom) on the PowerShell UserVoice site for this issue.